# solving equation in mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve:

```
    a x^(1 + m) y[x]^n + 2 y'[x] + x y''[x]=0

         with        y[0] = 1; y'[0] = 0;
```

for general m and n not (specific values) using Taylor series, is possible to do it in mathematica for high order?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can not do it when both $n,m$ are undefined.

It can do it when $n$ undefined but $m$ has specific value.

It can not do it when $m$ is undefined but $n$ has specific value. So this is the best what Mathematica can do now and you hit the limit of the current cutting edge Mathematical technology.

```
ClearAll[a, m, n, y, x];
m = 2;
ode = a x^(1 + m) y[x]^n + 2 y'[x] + x y''[x] == 0
ic = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[a, m, n, y, x];
n = 2;
ode = a x^(1 + m) y[x]^n + 2 y'[x] + x y''[x] == 0
ic = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note [AsymptoticDSolveValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html) was added in 2018 (11.3)

Comment: Dear Nasser, many thanks, I have version 11, so the above code is not working .

Comment: @user62716   This function was added in 11.3. Will update the answer with this.

Comment: Dear Nasser, so it can not be done if we write a code for Taylor series, when m,n undefined?

Comment: we have to find y''(0),y'''(0),y''''(0)....etc, then we can write the series?

Comment: @user62716 it is much more complicated than that. You need to solve the ODE using series method. Depending on singularity types, different series method is used. I think you need to lookup textbook that explains how to solve ODE's using series method. This buffer is too small to explain it all. I took a whole course on this one subject, and was hard subject.

Comment: Thanks Nasser I always trust you...Best regards